# How to import local image using knitr for markdown

Tags: html, image, markdown, figure, knitr

I have an externally created png image in a local directory that I'd like to import to a report using knitr. The ultimate target filetype is html. I have no trouble getting my own figures to appear when I create them with R code, but I'm at a loss what I would have thought was a simpler problem.

While I'm at it, how would I import a figure for which I have a url?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you already have a local image, you can just use the HTML or markdown syntax to include it in your document. [HTML syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp) is `<img src="path/to/your/image" />` and [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img) is `![title](path/to/your/image)`.

Comment: Is there a way to resize and center the image with rmarkdown in RStudio?

Comment: @PauloCardoso New posts for new questions please.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not asking anything different but a improvement to your answer. The addi could be as simple as 'No. there is not' or 'Yes, adding a piece of code'. But thank you anyway for taking your time to comment.

Comment: @PauloCardoso That is fine. Then my answer is, Yes, I have already mentioned the HTML syntax.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625990/how-to-set-size-for-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown

Comment: @Yihui, it appears that the path can not contain spaces, as my attempts to enclose the path in quotes caused errors. Putting the file in a directory path where none of the directories had spaces in their names worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can include image in knitted html by using **knitr::include_graphics()** in R Markdown.

```
knitr::include_graphics(rep('path_of_image.png'))
```

Make sure that you use **' / '** in path instead of ' \ '.