# How to set size for local image using knitr for markdown?

Tags: image, r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I have a local image that I would like to include in an `.Rmd` file which I will then `knit` and convert to HTML slides with `Pandoc`. Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517020/how-to-import-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown/10522029#10522029), this will insert the local image :
`![Image Title](path/to/your/image)`

Is there a way to modify this code to also set the image size?

Comment: For finer control over sizes, you might end up having to use an [HTML img tag](http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/img.html)

Comment: second @Marius's comment:http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax says "As of this writing, Markdown has no syntax for specifying the dimensions of an image; if this is important to you, you can simply use regular HTML <img> tags."

Comment: the problem using HTML tags is that the image is no longer recognized as an external resource by the Rmd conversion process, so it won't be included in a stand-alone version of the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can also read the image using `png` package for example and plot it like a regular plot using `grid.raster` from the `grid` package.

````
```{r fig.width=1, fig.height=10,echo=FALSE}
library(png)
library(grid)
img <- readPNG("path/to/your/image")
 grid.raster(img)
```
````

With this method you have full control of the size of you image.

Comment: Thank you, this works using slidy. (Does not work as well with dzslides, but I don't believe it's an issue with the provided solution).

Comment: Quotes around filepath are required in `img <- readPNG("path/to/your/image")` but I wasn't able to edit the solution.

Comment: @AdamSmith I just copied your `path/to/your/image` from your question. Yes the path name is a string,, and you need quotes to define a string. Hope I am clear.

Comment: By running this under RStudio, you will create a huge margin to the rendered png.

Comment: Future readers: This answer is [outdated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36057971/2706569).

Answer (score 229):

The question is old, but still receives a lot of attention. As the existing answers are outdated, here a more up-to-date solution:

## Resizing local images

As of [`knitr` 1.12](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-knitr-version-112), there is the function `include_graphics`. From `?include_graphics` (emphasis mine):

> The major advantage of using this function is that it is portable in the sense that it works for all document formats that `knitr` supports, so you do not need to think if you have to use, for example, LaTeX or Markdown syntax, to embed an external image. **Chunk options related to graphics output that work for normal R plots also work for these images, such as `out.width` and `out.height`.**

#### Example:

````
```{r, out.width = "400px"}
knitr::include_graphics("path/to/image.png")
```
````

Advantages:

- Over [agastudy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15626317/2706569): No need for external libraries or for re-rastering the image.
- Over [Shruti Kapoor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15688836/2706569): No need to manually write HTML. Besides, the image is included in the self-contained version of the file.

---

## Including generated images

To compose the path to a plot that is *generated in a chunk* (but not included), the chunk options `opts_current$get("fig.path")` (path to figure directory) as well as `opts_current$get("label")` (label of current chunk) may be useful. The following example uses `fig.path` to include the second of two images which were generated (but not displayed) in the first chunk:

````
```{r generate_figures, fig.show = "hide"}
library(knitr)
plot(1:10, col = "green")
plot(1:10, col = "red")
```

```{r}
include_graphics(sprintf("%sgenerate_figures-2.png", opts_current$get("fig.path")))
```
````

The general pattern of figure paths is `[fig.path]/[chunklabel]-[i].[ext]`, where `chunklabel` is the label of the chunk where the plot has been generated, `i` is the plot index (within this chunk) and `ext` is the file extension (by default `png` in RMarkdown documents).

Comment: For pdf output, you will have to specify units for the figure dimensions, e.g. `out.width='100pt'`, otherwise latex will throw an error about illegal unit of measure.

Comment: Also works for MS Word output, but the out.width and out.height do not work

Comment: @andybega Thank you for your comment; I incorporated it into the answer.

Comment: you probably want `r, echo=FALSE, ...`

Comment: This is strange: it works with ioslides Rmd, but not with Rmd to word or html.  For the latter two, I get errors: pandoc: Could not fetch ~/Google Drive/SI/DataScience/UAC_JRI/output/Master_Report/SI_logo.png
~/Google Drive/SI/DataScience/UAC_JRI/output/Master_Report/SI_logo.png: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Comment: @jzadra Please create a new question with reproducible code for your issue. At the moment I cannot reproduce your issue (copied the second code snippet verbatim to an RMD file and knitted to HTML and Word).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728551/r-markdown-knit-fails-when-path-includes-for-html-pdf-document-but-works-for

Answer (score 154):

Un updated answer: in `knitr 1.17` you can simply use

```
![Image Title](path/to/your/image){width=250px}
```

**edit** as per comment from @jsb

Note this works only without spaces, e.g. {width=250px} not {width = 250px}

Comment: I tried this in knitr 1.16 and it didn't work when using ioslides. Has this feature then been removed or is it an ioslides issue?

Comment: Does not work for me either, on the latest version of all packages.

Comment: Works for me using knitr 1.17. Make sure you write without spaces, e.g. `{width=250px}` not `{width = 250px}`.

Comment: Works for me, easiest solution by far.

Comment: This wouldn't work for me using `xaringan` with `knitr_1.21`.

Comment: On ioslides this is not working yet, using knitr_1.21

Comment: For height AND width `{height=640px width=480px}` - a space between the two, not a comma or anything else.

Comment: with in percentage, e.g. `{width=100%}` works as well!

Answer (score 38):

Here's some options that keep the file self-contained without retastering the image:

### Wrap the image in `div` tags

```
<div style="width:300px; height:200px">
![Image](path/to/image)
</div>
```

### Use a stylesheet

#### test.Rmd

```
---
title: test
output: html_document
css: test.css
---

## Page with an image {#myImagePage}

![Image](path/to/image)
```

#### test.css

```
#myImagePage img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

If you have more than one image you might need to use the nth-child pseudo-selector for this second option.

Comment: this is a good solution but it can be used with html output only! The other output will ignore the setting

Comment: The `<div> ... </div>` solution seems very simple.  What is the `style` setting to re-scale an image to a fixed percent, maintaining the aspect ratio?

Comment: Try using % instead of px.

Comment: Can the `<div> ... </div>`  method be used inline with text? I want the image to side directly beside some regular text. Thx!

Comment: this can only be used with html content. I would recommend using knitr itself over this strategy

Answer (score 21):

If you are converting to HTML, you can set the size of the image using HTML syntax using:

```
  <img src="path/to/image" height="400px" width="300px" />
```

or whatever height and width you would want to give.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the image is no longer recognized as an external resource by the Rmd conversion process, so it won't be included in a stand-alone version of the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue today and found another option with `knitr 1.16` when knitting to PDF (which requires that you have pandoc installed):

`![Image Title](path/to/your/image){width=70%}`

This method may require that you do a bit of trial and error to find the size that works for you. It is especially convenient because it makes putting two images side by side a prettier process. For example:

`![Image 1](path/to/image1){width=70%}![Image 2](path/to/image2){width=30%}`

You can get creative and stack a couple of these side by side and size them as you see fit. See https://rpubs.com/RatherBit/90926 for more ideas and examples.

Comment: is this not exactly the same as my answer above?

Comment: @hermestrismegistus nearly, but I am using percent of width rather than pixel width. I found this option to be useful because in my particular case I was putting multiple images side by side, which behaved better this way that when I gave exact width

Answer (score 8):

Another option that worked for me is playing with the dpi option of `knitr::include_graphics()` like this:

````
```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("path/to/image.png", dpi = 100)
```
````

... which sure (unless you do the math) is trial and error compared to defining dimensions in the chunk, but maybe it will help somebody.

Answer (score 4):

The knitr::include_graphics solution worked well for resizing the figures, but I was unable to figure out how to use it to produce side-by-side resized figures.  I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38660665/7020747) useful for doing so.