# Include images for pdf and html format

Tags: rstudio, markdown

I am trying to find an easy way to include images in knit `pdfs` and `html`. It would be nice to write one set of instructions that are easily converted to either format. I read here:

[Insert picture/table in R Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166624/insert-picture-table-in-r-markdown)

that the best way to include graphics is with a code chunk. It seems like it should work both for knitting pdfs as well as html. However, it only includes the graphics in `pdf` whereas it is missing from the `html`. The following is an MWE.

````
---
title: "a title"
author: "a"
date: "March 3, 2016"

# header-includes: \usepackage{graphicx}
# output:
#   pdf_document:
#     toc: true
#     toc_depth: 3                    # default = 3
#     number_sections: true           # add section numbering to headers

output:
  html_document:                  
    toc: true                     
    toc_float:                    
      collapsed: false              
      toc_depth: 4                  
    number_sections: true         
    highlight: tango              
    theme: simplex
---

### Support Vector Machines (SVMs)

SVM optimal hyperplane:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="A caption", out.width = '100%', fig.align = 'center'}
# https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html
knitr::include_graphics("./All_Figures/Chapter8/8.3.pdf")
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: your image is a PDF File

---

It always helps to include a minimal, reproducible example. As the path to your image was not provided, I have created one here which creates a local file `cars.pdf`:

````
---
title: Images in Knitr
output: 
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r}
# Create an example plot
pdf("cars.pdf")
plot(cars)
dev.off()

```

```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("cars.pdf")
```
````

Comparing the HTML and PDF, we can see the behaviour you report, whereby the images aren't shown in the HTML:

[image]

The problem stems from the image being saved as a PDF. From my understanding, HTML has no native way to display such images. It therefore doesn't display the image within the output.

As a workaround, you would be better to save the graphic as a PNG or JPEG.