# RMarkdown: ! Package pdftex.def Error; online image not found?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am running into a problem when trying to include a web-based image within a R Markdown PDF document.

**Minimal Example**:

```
---
title: "Random"
output: pdf_document
---

![Benjamin Bannekat](https://octodex.github.com/images/bannekat.png)
```

Knitting the above results in the error:

> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `https://octodex.github.com/images/bannekat.pn
>       g' not found.

However, if I use the following code, the image shows up:

```
---
title: "Random"
output:
  html_document: default
  html_notebook: default
---

![Benjamin Bannekat](https://octodex.github.com/images/bannekat.png)
```

The same code works fine when output is HTML.

How can I make the image show up in a PDF document?

Comment: Hope the answer helps. Just checking: why are you specifying the image path within a code chunk them wrapping it in `cat()`? You could just display the code outside as I have edited the question to do. I would still recommend the use of `include_graphics` as per my answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are knitting to PDF, the file has to run through LaTeX. LaTeX has no built-in capacity to display files hosted on the web, as highlighted [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document).

The best workaround for this is to download the web image to your local directory, and then specify this as a file path.

The following code downloads the image using the [download.file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html) function, and then displays in using `include_graphics`. The benefit of include graphics is that it allows you to specify the width of the image in the output document, which I set to 40 pixels.

````
---
title: "Random"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r results = 'asis', out.width="40px"}
download.file(url = "https://octodex.github.com/images/bannekat.png",
          destfile = "image.png",
          mode = 'wb')
knitr::include_graphics(path = "image.png")
```
````

[image]

> Find out more reasons why `include_graphics` should be used to include graphics in R Markdown documents. Check out [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856416/7347699) for more details why.