# image file not found from URL in r-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, xelatex

I used to be able to render images in r-markdown using a URL with the following code `![](https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark)` but I get a file not found error `! LaTeX Error: File https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark' not found`.
Am I missing packages? This code still works on some shiny apps published a few month ago.

Below the a working file r-markdown file:

```
---
title: "Test"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{graphicx}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    keep_tex: yes
classoption: article
papersize: A4
fontsize: 10pt
geometry: margin=0.9in
linestretch: 1.15
---
## R Markdown
![](https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark)
```

Comment: The image URL returns a 404. Append the missing `.png` and you should be golden.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. R-markdown does not require the file type. Unfortunately, this does not make a difference.

Comment: I don't have TeX installed, so I can't test with pdf output, but at least with html output, adding the `.png` solves the problem.

Comment: @PhilippR Ah yes, I can reproduce this. See <https://stackoverflow.com/q/51287734/2425163> for an answer. (Also, technically, it's only the graphicx package that doesn't require the file type.)

Comment: Ok, that points me in the right direction. What strikes me is that I have code running that works well with the syntax above. I am looping through the images to download them for the report. Not sure how this will work in the cloud hosted shiny apps.

Answer (score 3):

The LaTeX *graphicx* package does not include an http client, it is therefore not able to pull the image from the internet. However, a lot of the conversion work from Markdown to LaTeX is performed by pandoc, which *can* get this image. One just needs to tell pandoc to store all images locally by passing the `--extract-media` option. This allows LaTeX to find the images when it is invoked by RMarkdown.

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: ["--extract-media", "."]
---
```

The above will store all images in the same directory as the Rmd file. The files will be named using SHA1 hashes, so you might want to use a separate directory for these files instead.

Comment: Thanks, that works great for local files, but does this work in _shinyapps_? Has this been a default setting in previous _pandoc_ installations? I am still trying to understand how my older apps are still functioning without the option in ordinary _rmarkdown->xelatex_.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect that this used to work because pandoc directly created the PDF, while R Markdown will now use pandoc to generate LaTeX and do the final invocations of XeLaTeX by itself. The release notes of R Markdown 1.1 (~ 2016) mention changes to the way `keep_tex` works, which might have caused the change in behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I am generating pdf's in `xelatex` and while this works locally I cannot get the images to work in my shiny app. I am using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800883/using-image-in-r-markdown-report-downloaded-from-shiny-app) to generate the pdf from shiny app data. How to reference the working directory of the `extracted-media` in shiny?

Comment: I know next to nothing about shiny, sorry. Might be worth a new question?

Comment: New question regarding web images in LaTex PDF in Shinyapps posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652934/latex-pdf-with-images-from-web-in-shinyapp).