# How to include a png file in R flexdashboard

Tags: png, flexdashboard

Could you please help me in finding the right code to print a png image inside a R flexdashboard?

Here my code chunk:

```
    ---
    title: "Analyse des installations PV - Les Vergers"
    author: "Dario Santandrea"
    date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
    output:
     flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: rows
        vertical_layout: fill
     runtime: shiny

    ---
```

#### First attempt

```
renderImage({

  outfile <- tempfile(fileext = "X:/LesVergers/Analyse/BilanSolaire/Figures/Solar_angle_scheme.png")

  png(outfile, width = 500, height = 400)
  dev.off()

  }

)
```

#### Second attempt

```
#knitr::include_graphics("X:/LesVergers/Analyse/BilanSolaire/Figures/Solar_angle_scheme.png")
```

The image i've been trying to print doesn't simply appear in the flexdashboard

Answer (score 4):

flexdashboard is essentially Markdown. Thus see e.g. [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166624/insert-picture-table-in-r-markdown).

````
```{r picture, echo = F, fig.cap = "Title", out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("picture.png")
```
````

Just place this chunk within the standard flexdashboard layout:

````
BLOCK1
=====================================

Row {data-width=1000}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### A picture

```{r picture, echo = F, fig.cap = "Title", out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("picture.png")
```
````