# add and resize a local image to a .Rmd file in RStudio that will produce a pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to add and resize a local image to a `.Rmd` file in RStudio that will produce a pdf. I can add the file easily with

`![My caption.](path/file.png)`

but I have not figured out how to control the size of the image. I tried HTML code with a width attribute, but the image would not appear (I think this only works if outputting to HTML).

`<img src="path/file.png" width="200px" />`

I could not get [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/how-to-change-image-size-markdown) to work:

`![My caption.](path/file.png =250x)`

Is there a way to modify the Rmarkdown script to modify the size of the local image with only RMarkdown and base R?

There is [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625990/how-to-set-size-for-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown) to use the `png` and `grid` packages, but I am limited to base R for my problem. For other users, however, I think this looks like a good solution.

Comment: possible dups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625990/how-to-set-size-for-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/how-to-change-image-size-markdown

Comment: @Edi, thanks. I clarified that I am looking for a base R approach.

Comment: You can use raw latex to include a figure in pdf_output: `\includegraphics[width=250pt]{path/file.png}`

Comment: @tmpname12345, you're right. i did not even think to try that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From @tmpname12345

You can use raw latex to include a figure in pdf_output: `\includegraphics[width=250pt]{path/file.png}`

Answer (score 10):

You can also specify the size of the image like so:

```
![](filepath\file.jpg){ width=50% }
```

The `width` and `height` attributes on images are treated specially. When used without a unit, the unit is assumed to be pixels. However, any of the following unit identifiers can be used: `px`, `cm`, `mm`, `in`, `inch` and `%`. There must not be any spaces between the number and the unit.

Source: [Pandoc's RMarkdown Documentation - Images](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#images)

Comment: I think this answer is the simplest solution. But it works only in RMarkdown (not in Markdown).

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone arrives here from google looking to insert an image into an RMarkdown html_document:

#### Insert directly

This method is arguably the easiest to change size

```
<img src="mypic.png" alt="drawing" width="200" height="50"/>
```

#### Another way

Note you can mix measurements like so: `height="200" width=60%`

```
![some caption text here](mypic.png){height="200" width=60% }
```

#### Insert via RMarkdown chunk

```
knitr::include_graphics("mypic.png")
```

#### Insert directly from URL

````
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '60%'}
image_url <- "http://www.example.com/mypic.png"
```
<center><img src="`r image_url`"></center>
````

Comment: The image inserted directly from URL is not resized to 60% width.

Comment: @gyaan.anveyshak interesting. I wonder if something like `<center><img src="\`r image_url\` width="60%"></center>` would work?

Answer (score 1):

A longer example with latex.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=250pt]{../images/pricePlot2006_1.5.png}
\caption{Prices through time.}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

Other figures created in the .Rmd are numbered automatically.

````
```{r namedBlock, fig.cap = "Lots of cars."}
plot(mtcars)
```
````