# R Markdown knit fails when path includes "~" for html/pdf document but works for ioslides

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

As of knitr 1.12, there is the function include_graphics. From ?include_graphics:

> The major advantage of using this function is that it is portable in
>   the sense that it works for all document formats that knitr supports,
>   so you do not need to think if you have to use, for example, LaTeX or
>   Markdown syntax, to embed an external image.

It seems that `include_graphics()` handles paths with "~" in them (shortcut to user directory) when knitting an ioslides Rmarkdown presentation, but fails when knitting a word/html document.

Reproducible example for ioslides (note that these will make a copy of the Rlogo.png onto your desktop:

````
---
title: "Rlogo ioslides"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Images?

```{r}
require(knitr)
rlogo <- paste0(.libPaths(), "/png/img/Rlogo.png")
include_graphics(rlogo)

file.copy(from = rlogo, to = "~/Desktop")
include_graphics("~/Desktop/Rlogo.png")
```
````

> processing file: rlogo.Rmd
>
> /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m
>   -RTS rlogo.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output rlogo.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --variable transition=0.4 --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/ioslides/default.html
>   --include-in-header /var/folders/5_/l71sk6kn29z17n011g8kld5m0000gp/T//RtmpKAAz4I/rmarkdown-str91efb7c6c16.html
>   --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
>   output file: rlogo.knit.md
>
> /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m
>   -RTS rlogo.utf8.md --to ioslides_presentation.lua --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output /var/folders/5_/l71sk6kn29z17n011g8kld5m0000gp/T//RtmpKAAz4I/ioslides-output91ef159c1e3e.html
>   --slide-level 2
>
> Output created: rlogo.html

And reproducible failure for word/html document:

````
---
title: "Rlogo word/html"
output:
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---

## Images?

```{r}
require(knitr)
rlogo <- paste0(.libPaths(), "/png/img/Rlogo.png")
include_graphics(rlogo)

file.copy(from = rlogo, to = "~/Desktop")
include_graphics("~/Desktop/Rlogo.png")
```
````

> processing file: rlogo.Rmd
>
> /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m
>   -RTS rlogo.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output rlogo.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html
>   --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /var/folders/5_/l71sk6kn29z17n011g8kld5m0000gp/T//RtmpCR2Vrn/rmarkdown-str91681de2b0f3.html
>   --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
>   output file: rlogo.knit.md
>
> pandoc: Could not fetch ~/Desktop/Rlogo.png ~/Desktop/Rlogo.png:
>   openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory) Error:
>   pandoc document conversion failed with error 67 Execution halted

I'm using MacOS Sierra.

Why is this failing in one case but not the other?

Comment: What OS are you using? And what is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: @MrFlick I've added to my original post.

Comment: FYI, the same question was asked here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1411

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should work if you use `path.expand('~/path')` instead, I would expect.  The problem is the resolution of the `~`.  Some functions call `path.expand` for you - others might require you to do it yourself.  That or relative paths are an option if things are set up relatively.  I prefer the relative path approach because it works nicely in `R` and with github, etc.

EDIT: Per @yihui's [response](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1411) - `normalizePath` is another tool to keep in mind.

In your example:

```
...
include_graphics(path.expand("~/Desktop/Rlogo.png"))
...
```