# Resizing external image in Rmarkdown: html vs. ioslides output

Tags: html, image, r-markdown, image-resizing, ioslides

I'm using external images in an Rmarkdown document that is meant to be rendered as ioslides and I need to easily resize them.

Doing it the html way works both when I `knit` to ioslides and to html_document.

```
<img src="image.png" style="height: 200px"/>
```

Doing it the markdown way like below works when I `knit` to html_document but NOT when I `knit` to ioslides (i.e., the image isn't resized).

```
![](image.png){width=200px}
```

My question is: **how can I make the markdown resizing approach work when the output is ioslides?**

Comment: You will have to use a workaround like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36057971/1777111

Answer (score 3):

Atongsa's solution:     using chunkoptions

````
```{r, out.width = "900px", out.height= "500px", fig.cap= "cite from 
NATURE REVIEW_Deep_learning", echo=FALSE}

knitr::include_graphics("/home/atongsa/Pictures/Screenshot")
```
````

then the imagine is ok

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Atongsa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47185785/6170115), you can manage the aspect ratio using percentages.

Eg `out.width='90%'`