# RMarkdown - knitr - png size won't change

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to make a png image longer, but any setting I change has no effect. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625990/how-to-set-size-for-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown/36057971#36057971), three different attempts are shown below. The options change the ggplot object in the last chunk properly. I am using RMarkdown and knitr.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=9, fig.height=6) 

library(RODBC)
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)
library(doParallel)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

```

```{r , echo=FALSE, fig.height=50 }
knitr::include_graphics("data_sim_plot.png")
```

```{r , echo=FALSE, out.height=50, fig.height=50 }
knitr::include_graphics("data_sim_plot.png")
```

```{r , echo=FALSE, out.height=50, fig.height=50 }
knitr::opts_current$set(fig.height=20) 
knitr::include_graphics("data_sim_plot.png")
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
# a different ggplot object
readRDS("gg.rds")
```
````

Answer (score 0):

````
```{r , echo=FALSE, out.width= "500px"}
knitr::include_graphics("index.jpg")
````

````
```{r , echo=FALSE, out.width= "800px" }
knitr::include_graphics("index.jpg")
````

They gave pictures with different length. Is this what you want?

Comment: It results in different lengths only up to a certain width. For example, 1000px results in the same dimensions as 10000px.  I think I didn't realize that 1. knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=9, fig.height=6) sets the maximum sizes and you cannot exceed those and 2. the aspect ratio of the image is locked. I think I need to adjust the aspect ratio myself