# Changing R Markdown figure width

Tags: r

I have been trying to use the "timevis" package to create a timeline of events and produce a pdf. I am however  unable to resize the figure to fit 100% of the pdf width and remove the zoom in buttons on the plot.

````
```{r}
library(tibble)
library(timevis)
data <- tribble(~id, ~content, ~start, ~end,
                1,  "CSS 1", "1996-12-17", NA, 
                2,  "CSS 2", "1998-05-01", NA, 
                3,  "CSS 3", "1999-06-01", NA, 
                4,   "HTML", "1989-01-01", NA, 
                5, "HTML 2", "1995-11-24", NA, 
                6, "HTML 3", "1997-01-14", NA, 
                7, "HTML 4", "1997-12-18", NA,
                8, "HTML 5", "2014-10-28", NA, 
                9,    "CSS", "1994-10-10", NA, 
                10,    "JS", "1995-12-04", NA)

timevis(data)
```
````

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The plot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojwxA.png

Comment: Did you try changing `fig.width` and `fig.height` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625990/how-to-set-size-for-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown

Comment: I tried setting the fig.width=100% out.width=100% doesnt seem to work

Comment: @zstar `fig.width` and `fig.height` need to be specified in inches, see [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html).