# Inserting images from url to Rmakdown using the knitr::include_graphics

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to reproduce an image from `pandoc` to `Rmarkdown`.

The pandoc way :

```
 ![](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563204996-8965f0a4a860?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80)
```

My trial Rmarkdown:

```
url <- "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563204996-8965f0a4a860?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80"

knitr::include_graphics(url, dpi = 600)
```

I am able to knit the file and able to generate the image same as pandoc but also additionally would like to set the output **width** of the figure to `600px` which I am trying by placing in `dpi=600`.

I am skeptical about that is the image actually resized after performing this or is there an alternative way?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625990/how-to-set-size-for-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the `dpi` argument of `knitr::include_graphics()` also doesn't change the size of the image for HTML or DOCX output. What does work though issetting the chunk-option `out.width`. You can use pixel values (see below) or percent (e.g. "25%").

````
```{r out.width="300px"}
url <- "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563204996-8965f0a4a860?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=934&q=80"
knitr::include_graphics(url)

```
````

See chapter 5.4 of the [R-Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html) for more details.