# Path to image in my package for R mark down

Tags: r

I made a pakcage `BayesianXXX` in which I also made vignette by `YYY.Rmd` file in its path `BayesianXXX/vignettes/YYY.Rmd`.

I want to paste image in `YYY.Rmd`  and to do so, the following Rmd script is required in the  `YYY.Rmd`.

```
![title](path/to/your/image)
```

For example, If we made `ZZZ.jpg` in a image file in the inst directory, that is, `BayesianXXX/inst/image/ZZZ.jpg`, then how to specify its path in the code `![title](path/to/your/image)`

Ref:[How to import local image using knitr for markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517020/how-to-import-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your file path `BayesianXXX/inst/image/ZZZ.jpg`

```
system.file("image", "ZZZ.jpg", package="BayesianXXX")
```

Should work as long as the package is installed on the system (and in one of the library locations from `.libPaths()`).

In the `YYY.Rmd`, you can then use inline code:

```
`r paste0("![](",system.file("image", "ZZZ.jpg", package="BayesianXXX"), ")")`
```

Or in a chunk using `cat` and `results='asis'`

Comment: Thank you very much !! Thank you!! I wanted to use the `system.file()` but I cannot come up how to execute such R script from Rmd file. I can do. Thank you !!